# How to put Adsense in the hot towel SPA?

Tags: single-page-application, adsense, hottowel

I'm trying to familiarize myself with Hot Towel SPA template, so I had tried to add one adsense (google) in the initial page (home.html), but when the page is rendered in the browser, the  tag was removed, Any tip or help?
  The same thing happen when I Tried to add some social buttons (http://www.sharethis.com/).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place the adsense and the analytics from google in the "index.html" page. All other pages will open over this page.
   I made my adsense to show up after the load page, moving the div to the right location.